# How to programmatically change columns in data.table by column name as in shiny input?

Tags: r, data.table

How can i achieve the desired result in code below?

```
library(magrittr); library(ggplot2); library(data.table)
dt <- diamonds %>%  setDT  

input <- list()
input$col = "cut"

dt[ , (input$col) :=  ifelse( get(input$col) == "Good", "Bon", get(input$col))] # Original post had typo : ... get(input$col):= "Good" ... instead of ... == ...
```

so that a user can enter (eg. via shiny app), in which columns the word replacement need to be done?

The code above generates this error:

```
Error in `:=`(get(input$col), "Good") : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the following is the shortest (to write) and fastest (to execute):

```
dt [ get (input$col) == "Good", (input$col) := "Bon"]
```

I wonder why i did not think about it earlier? (and others too?) ...

Output:

```
> dt
       carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
    1:  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43
    2:  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326 3.89 3.84 2.31
    3:  0.23       Bon     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31
    4:  0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334 4.20 4.23 2.63
    5:  0.31       Bon     J     SI2  63.3    58   335 4.34 4.35 2.75
   ---                                                               
53936:  0.72     Ideal     D     SI1  60.8    57  2757 5.75 5.76 3.50
53937:  0.72       Bon     D     SI1  63.1    55  2757 5.69 5.75 3.61
53938:  0.70 Very Good     D     SI1  62.8    60  2757 5.66 5.68 3.56
53939:  0.86   Premium     H     SI2  61.0    58  2757 6.15 6.12 3.74
53940:  0.75     Ideal     D     SI2  62.2    55  2757 5.83 5.87 3.64
```

Answer (score 1):

You original code will work, if you change the second `:=` to `==`, like this:

```
dt[ , (input$col):=ifelse( get(input$col)=="Good", "Bon", get(input$col))]
```

However, you might want to consider in general, using `[["col"]]` instead:

```
dt[ , (input[["col"]]):=ifelse( get(input[["col"]])== "Good", "Bon", get(input[["col"]]))]
```

Finally, you can also use `set()`, since you are updating `cut` in-place:

```
set(dt, j=input$col, value=ifelse(dt[[input$col]]=="Good", "Bon", dt[[input$col]]))
```

Not that in all isntances, that `cut` is a factor, and in fact is numeric, so the way you are replacing here will cause the other values of `cut` to revert to their underlying numeric format. You could alternatively do this:

```
levels(dt[[input$col]])[levels(dt[[input$col]])=="Good"] <- "Bon"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the problem with factors! I found though a (much) faster/shorter way - posted as answer below. Supprizingly, it also handles the factor problem. What do you think? Agree?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `.SDcols`

```
library(data.table)
v1 <- input$col
dt[, (v1) := fcase(.SD[[1]] != "Good", .SD[[1]], default = "Bon"), 
        .SDcols = v1]
```